# What are the difference between `Ploeh.AutoFixture` and `AutoFixture`?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, autofixture, automocking

### What are the difference between `Ploeh.AutoFixture` and `AutoFixture`?

I have a project where I cannot use 
`using AutoFixture;`

However, I have to use
`using Ploeh.AutoFixture`

What is the difference between these two and what would be pros and cons?

However, I also found another nuget package which enables me to add `using AutoFixture;`only. What would be the best option?

I couldn't find the answer in stackoverflow. Any answer will enrich the community.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because `AutoFixture` is a namespace within `Ploeh`.

Comment: Check the release notes https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/v4.0-Release-Notes#%EF%B8%8F%EF%B8%8F-removed-the-ploeh-namespace-and-assembly-name-prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one with `Ploeh.AutoFixture` is an older version. The `Ploeh` prefix was removed from the project about five months ago: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/commit/236e3d76d37fc615c693370f0385af39c1350394